# e-e scattering time in graphene

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I think its worth writing my second question in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193485/e-e-scattering-rate-in-normal-fermi-liquid-and-in-graphene) as a separate one.

In normal Fermi liquid, the electron-electron scattering time $\tau_{e-e}$ is about:

$$
\tau_{e-e} \approx \frac{\hbar E_F}{k_B^2 T^2}
$$

What about the time in graphene at half filling?